# How to prevent selected elements from collecting inside search box in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 as a dropdown with search, with dropdown options linking to external sites. This means that I do not need Select2 to collect the options when selected into the search bar (it collects each one selected until the X is clicked to close each one).

I can't seem to figure out the best way to remove this functionality. I have created text hyperlink buttons floating to the right of each dropdown option, but I want to prevent the user from clicking on the option itself and having their selected options collect in the search bar.

Can anyone please advise the best way to achieve/remove this?